# Refreshing Component and not all view with react

Tags: reactjs

Im already learning about to fetch data from REST API with react, i have to components (form for submit and a card for get data) both summon from parent component (App), and is working, so i got to push new todo to db and get the news values on my card component, but instead only render cards components, render the all App (incluyed the form component), what am i doing wrong guys?

This is the parent Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import SampleCard from './components/SampleCard';
import Form from './components/Form';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTasks()
  }

  getTasks =_=> {
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/users')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({ data: data.data }))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.getTasks}>
        <Form />
        </form>
        {this.state.data.map((row, i) => (
          <div key={i}>
            <SampleCard row={row} />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

    )
  }


}

export default App;
```

This, the form component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Form extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tasks: {
                task: '',
                status: ''
            }
        }
    }

    addTask = _ => {
        const { tasks } = this.state
        fetch(`http://localhost:4000/users/add?task=${tasks.task}&status=${tasks.status}`)
        .catch( err => console.log(err))
    }

    render() {
        const { tasks } = this.state
        return (
            <div className="Form container mt-3">
                <div className="input-group mb-3">
                    <div className="input-group-prepend">
                        <span className="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">
                            Define Task!
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        value={tasks.task}
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ tasks: { ...tasks, task: e.target.value } })}
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Task"
                        aria-label="Task"
                        aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="input-group mb-3">
                    <div className="input-group-prepend">
                        <span className="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">
                            Define Status!
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        value={tasks.status}
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ tasks: { ...tasks, status: e.target.value } })}
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Status"
                        aria-label="Status"
                        aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
                    />
                </div>
                <button 
                type="Submit" 
                className="btn btn-outline-success d-flex mr-auto"
                onClick={this.addTask}
                >
                Add
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Form;
```

and this the card component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class SampleCard extends Component {


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container pt-5">
        <div className="col-xs-12">
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-header">
            <h5 className="card-title">{this.props.row.task}</h5>
            </div>
            <div className="card-body">
              <h4 className="card-title">{this.props.row.created_at}</h4>
              {this.props.row.status === 1 ? (
                <h3 className="card-title">Pending</h3>
              ) : (
                <h3 className="card-title">Completed</h3>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not preventing default submit behavior. Do it like this

```
getTasks = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
fetch('http://localhost:4000/users')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => this.setState({ data: data.data }))
.catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Whenever using submit with a form, use `e.preventDefault()` it prevents refreshing.

Comment: thanks mate, but show to "TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined', i was google about preventDefault but i trying different ways to implement it, but i wasnt =(

Comment: did you try typing it like this? `getTasks = (e) =>` instead of  `getTasks =_=> `

Comment: you can also try by changing this line `<form onSubmit={this.getTasks}>` to `<form onSubmit={(e) => this.getTasks(e)}>`